# Dropdownlist Selected value does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to edit a record in my application, I go to edit page but I don't know why my dropdownlists don't show selected values that when I selected in create page. this is my codes :

My controller :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    book book = db.books.Find(id);
    if (book == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.books = new SelectList(db.books, "id", "name", book.value);
    return View(book);
}
```

and my action :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownList("value", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.books , "Choose.")
}
```

What is problem? In trance I can see that one on options is selectedvalue, but dropdownlist does not show selected value. why?

Comment: `books.value` shouldn't that be `book`

Comment: @KyorCode it's book, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
ViewBag.books = new SelectList(db.books, "id", "name", books.value);
```

into

```
ViewBag.books = new SelectList(db.books, "id", "name", book.id);
```

Comment: Try changing dropdownlist declaration in the view into: @Html.DropDownList("books") Then dropdown list shoudl be populated from Viewbag and set on the Id you set in controller